# Could not load lang::java::jdt::Java

Tags: rascal

When trying to import JAVA modules I receive an error:

```
// JAVA imports
import lang::java::jdt::Java;
import lang::java::jdt::JDT;
import lang::java::jdt::JavaADT;
```

Could not load lang::java::jdt::Java
In the console:

```
rascal>import lang::java::jdt::Java;

|prompt:///|(0,29,<1,0>,<1,29>): Could not import module lang::java::jdt::Java: can not find in search path
Advice: |http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/ModuleImport/ModuleImport.html|
```

I'm using Eclipse and am trying to use the AstNode datatype. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDT modules have been replaced a while back by the m3 model.

While they are a bit different, the AST part should be comparable.
Check the [m3 ast documentation](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/analysis/m3/AST/AST.html) and the [Measuring java recipe](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Recipes/Metrics/MeasuringJava/MeasuringJava.html).

Is this an old project you are trying to get up and running?

Comment: It's a new project, so I'm free to use the new models. Thanks!